# Is this different logic right for Prime Number

Tags: java, primes

I am new to java. I am trying to create a program to find Prime number. I know there are lot of solutions to get prime numbers but today I coded a program where I just checked that if the given number is divided by 2,3,5 or 7 than it is not prime. Is this logic right or insufficient to calculate the prime number. For reference; here is the code, surprisingly it is evaluating right.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prime 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number");
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        if(n==1) {
            System.out.println(n+" is not prime");
        } else if(n==2) {
            System.out.println(n+" is prime");
        } else if(n%2==0 || n%3==0 || n%5==0 || n%7==0) {
            System.out.println(n+" is not prime");
        } else {
            System.out.println(n+" is prime");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is right. Our code is just same using result of 2,3,5 and 7. But maybe you're question is off for this site?

Comment: I think to make sure it i really prime number you could write this code: int i,m=0,flag=0;    
  int n=17;//it is the number to be checked  
  m=n/2;    
  for(i=2;i<=m;i++){    
   if(n%i==0){    
   System.out.println("Number is not prime");    
   flag=1;    
   break;    
   }    
  }    
  if(flag==0)    
  System.out.println("Number is prime");

Comment: This is a perfect example of why developers can't be trusted to test their own code :-)

Comment: @jace Hey Sorry. I was confused regarding the logicthats why I asked. I dont want to stick with wrong logic.

Comment: @FadySaad hey thanks for reply. I know that logic and thats why I posted here that ,what about this logic.

Comment: @AndrewShepherd Hey It is working fine for 11, 13 and far greater values.

Comment: @user3622254 - Try reading the answers :-)

Comment: yeah it will really works as for all numbers divisible by 2,3,5 and 7 will be eliminated as prime. Already tested that logic years ago :) But you have to catch 2,3,5 and 7 also .

Comment: oh Wait, i forgot how I computed the greater numbers if I also used other prime to divide :D let there answers be heard

Comment: I think you need to add if number square root is not whole number? sorry really forgot but you can try :)

Comment: thanks everyone. now I know this logic is totally flawed. 121 is a good example where it is the square of 11 and this program is still showing 121 as prime which is wrong. 
@AndrewShepherd haha..true that..btw I am applying for automation testing positions. :)

Answer (score 4):

> Is this logic right or insufficient to calculate the prime number.

No.  You are only testing for numbers divisible by a (small) subset of primes.  For larger numbers it will incorrectly report some numbers as prime when they aren't prime.

Also some small primes are incorrectly reported as not prime.

> For reference; here is the code, surprisingly it is evaluating right.

That simply means you have not tested it for a number that is not the product of 2 (or more) primes that are greater than 7.  Try 121.

Or for 3, 5 or 7.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not enough. For small numbers it will work, but then will come number that is not multiple of these, but is multiple of 11, 13, 17 and so on. You will have to check against all primes that are smaller than square root of your number.
And as Nico pointed out it will also mark some primes as not primes.

Answer (score 0):

It's error! First of all,the 3,5,7 all is pirme, view the code, if input 3, this program will print "3 is not prime", then input 5,7 ... , it's same as after, so the logic is not right!

Comment: 3 is prime but it is a really small prime -- barely counts.

Comment: Good catch. Another reason.

Comment: @Jeff big or small, 3 is prime. The OP's program is flawed in multiple ways. This is just one of them.

Answer (score 0):

Better check for [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-of-eratosthenes/), it is the best solution to get prime numbers plus faster performance. You may not get it right away but it's worth it

Answer (score -1):

I think this code is working fine for prime numbers.  Let me know if there is anything to improve.

---

```
package primenumber;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrimeNumber 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a number");
        int n = input.nextInt();

            if (n==2 || n==3 || n==5|| n==7)
            {
                System.out.printf("%d is a prime number\n", n);
            }
            else if(n%2!=0 && n%3!=0 && 
                    n%5!=0 && n%7!=0 && n%Math.sqrt(n)!=0)
            {
                System.out.printf("%d is a prime number\n", n);
            }

            else
            {
            System.out.printf("%d is not a prime number\n", n);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: is 143 a prime?

Comment: No. The code is not completely right? Thanks for pointing out.  Is there any other code which finds out prime numbers accurately?

Comment: lots and lots of [them](https://www.google.com/search?q=primality+test). here [on this site](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bprimes%5D+test+is%3Aq); also on [Rosettacode.org](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Primality_by_trial_division). (not my downvote btw).